# Inequality concerning operator norm

Tags: real-analysis

I have difficulty understanding the following statement in PMA by Rudin (aka. "Baby Rudin"):

> For $A\in L(\mathrm{R}^n,\mathrm{R}^m)$, define the norm $\|A\|$ to be the sup of all numbers $|Ax|$ where $x$ ranges over all vectors in $\mathrm{R^n}$ with $|x|\leq 1$. Observe that the inequality $|Ax|\leq \|A\||x|$ holds for all $x\in \mathrm{R^n}$.

The above inequality says $\frac{|Ax|}{|x|}\leq\|A\|$. But the $x$ here is not restricted to those with $|x|\leq 1$? 
I seriously have no clue why this holds. I heard that $\sup_{|x|\leq1}|Ax|=\sup_{|x|=1}|Ax|$. Is this true? And if so, how does it help to prove the above inequality?

Any comment is greatly appreciated.

Comment: In fact you have: $\sup_{|x|\le1}|Ax|=\sup_{|x|=1}|Ax|=\sup_{x\neq 0}\frac{|Ax|}{|x|}$

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to understand... Does $|Ax|$ get greater as $|x|$ get greater?

Comment: @Alice Take an arbitrary $x \in \mathbf{R}^n$ and consider $x/|x|$.

Comment: Suppose you have some x, then: $|A (\lambda x)| = \lambda |Ax|$ for $\lambda \ge 0$

Comment: @Noctune Thank you. I see. If we take the vector $x/|x|$ it is of norm 1. I get it now.

Comment: @HendryXT I see. So $|x|^{-1}|Ax|=|Ax/|x||$. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your first question: If $|x| > 1$, then simply replace $x$ with $|x|^{-1} x$ and use the absolute homogenity of the norm.

To answer your second question: The inequality $\sup \limits_{|x| \le 1} |Ax| \ge \sup \limits_{|x| = 1} |Ax|$ is obviously correct. To see the converse inequality, note that for every $x \ne 0$ with $|x| \le 1$ the inequality $$|Ax| = |x| \big|A|x|^{-1}x\big| \le  |A|x|^{-1}x| \le \sup \limits_{|y| = 1}|Ay|$$ 
holds, since $\big||x|^{-1}x\big| = 1$.

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation.